# Running Python & Django on IIS

Tags: asp.net, python, asp.net-mvc, apache, iis

Is it possible to run Python & Django on IIS?
I am going to be a Lead Developer in some web design company and right now they are using classic ASP and ASP.NET.
As far as I can see ASP.NET MVC is not mature. Should I recommend Python & Django stack?
If it's not possible to run Python on IIS what do you think I should do? Stick with ASP.NET which I don't know? I don't know python well as well but I'm more comfortable with it.
Can I run IIS and Apache in parallel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's two issue here, technological and psycological.

Technologically, yes, it's definitely possible. In fact, Django has a [wiki article](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoOnWindowsWithIISAndSQLServer) about this. Google also shows a lot of similar tutorials. Apache and IIS can also run on the same machine (I'm actually doing that right now from a development machine).

The bigger issue will be psycological, in the form of backlash you'll get from the other developers. I agree that Django kicks the pants off ASP.NET, but you're probably going to find that an ASP.NET shop is going to be married to ASP.NET and will likely ignore your suggestion to try anything else, much less Django.

Comment: Currently I will be in charge of a graphic designer and later on, I'll be in charge for other developers. As of now all of the development team is leaving. The only problem is that I'll have to maintain ASP and ASP.Net apps until I rewrite them all and there are more then 60 of them including pre-made sites. I hate this situation. Is there any magical solution to it?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Python is powerful, but not magical. Maintaining or migrating from legacy apps is no fun. Maintaining them will be the less expensive short term solution. If you want to move to Django in the long run, migrating will be more expensive in the short term, but cheaper in the long run.

Answer (score 5):

We've been running django on IIS for a couple of years using PyISAPIe. It's a fairly big site, about 150,000 users. We're moving to linux/apache though, partly cos PyISAPIe isn't great.

Case in point - WebKit browsers don't work well with it, it seems to mess up the chunking. That's tolerable for us as we are allowed to limit our users to FF/IE7+, but annoys me on a mac as I much prefer Safari to FF.