# Is Django and Active Python 2.x for production environments on Windows 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5?

Tags: python, django, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I like Django but I'm in a Microsoft shop.  Microsoft has an [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276494) showing how to get Python installed, but can you use it with Django, IIS 7.5 and Windows 2008 R2?

Comment: maybe this will help http://blog.wolfplusplus.com/?p=272 (my google skills are strong :P)

Answer (score 1):

I used http://django-windows-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ to successfully accomplish this.

Note that [Running Python & Django on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112525/running-python-django-on-iis) is a reasonably similar question here on stackoverflow.